# Simple ground connection when controlling with gpio different power supply

Tags: power-supply, led, stm32, grounding

I have a STM32F4 Discovery board and I want to activate a LED connected to an external power supply.

I could connect the LED to the 5V supply of the STM32F4 DISCOVERY but I'm testing this to use it with a load that will consume a lot of current, so I need that external power supply. In addition I'm planning to use a N-Channel MOSFET instead of the NPN transistor, but for the moment I'm just testing a main idea.

In order to correctly control the LED toggling I've had to connect the STM32F4 GND to the LED power supply GND using a simple cable (purple cable in the picture below).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx6uIl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If not, the LED is always turned on with a lower light intensisty (transistor not fully switched). I understand this is because there is a voltage offset between both grounds.

Is this procedure correct? If not, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the purple link to connect the grounds are needed for the transistor to work.